# How should we characterize a continuous family of continuous mappings?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, homotopy-theory

Let $S$ and $S'$ be two topological spaces. It is known that two continuous mappings $f,g:S\to S'$ are homotopic if there is a continous mapping
$$F:[0,1]\times S\to S'$$
with
$$F(0,\cdot)=f(\cdot)$$
$$F(1,\cdot)=g(\cdot)$$
The continuity of $F$ is defined because we can equip $[0,1]\times S$ with the product topology. But if we look at this another way, I believe it is natural and reasonable to say ($C(S;S')$ is the set of all continuous mappings $S\to S'$)
$$\tilde F:[0,1]\to C(S;S')\\
\quad\quad\ t\mapsto F(t,\cdot)$$
defines a **continuous family of continuous mappings $S\to S'$**. This means $C(S;S')$ should be equipped with a topology. My question is: how can we characterize this topology using the topology on $S$ and $S'$ only, without resorting to the product topology above? Let me rephrase in a few different ways:

(1) How can we characterize the topology on $C(S;S')$?

(2) What is a neighborhood of a mapping $f\in C(S;S')$?

(3) When can we say a sequence $f_n\in C(S;S')$ converges to $f\in C(S;S')$?

I think this is easier if $S$ or $S'$ has additional strcutures. For example when $S'$ is a normed vector space we can define a norm on $C(S;S')$ by
$$||F||=\sup_{x\in S}||F(x)||$$
But what about the most general case  where $S,S'$ are nothing but topological spaces?

Comment: Usually the set $C(S,S')$ is endowed with the *compact-open* topology. See any book on general topology. Doing so, you get a canonicial bijection between continuous maps (=homotopies) $S \times I \to S'$ and continuous maps $I \to C(S,S')$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can topologize $C(S, S')$ in a convenient way by taking the subsets $\mathcal{K}(C,V) = \{f \in C(S, S'): f[C] \subseteq V\} \subseteq C(S,S')$, where $C \subseteq X$ is a compact subspace and $V \subseteq Y$ is open, as a subbasis. The subsequently generated topology is the so-called *compact-open* topology.